# trouble returning an object, Bin, through a method. Needs to "Cast" or change to Object

Tags: java

I'm a beginner trying to learn java!

I am currently trying out the book Building Skills in Object-Oriented Design, and is currently working on the Roulette.

I have a class, Bin, which constructs a TreeSet which contains Outcome-objects. They are constructed in the Outcome class.

Now, I am working on the Wheel class, and here I am using new Vector(38) that I'm filling with 38 new Bin() s.

**Now, the issue.**

I want to create a method that retrieves a Bin-object from the Vector.

```
Bin get(int bin){
    return  bins.elementAt(bin);
}
```

This doesn't work and Eclipse is suggesting two fixes:

1: Add cast

2: Change Bin to Object

What is going on here? Why can't I return Bin the way I want to? When I cast or change to Object, it doesn't work.

[This is the Outcome class](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5458890)

[This is the Bin class](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5458896)

This is the Wheel class

```
package Roulette;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Wheel {

Vector bins;
Random rng;


Wheel(Random rng){
    rng =  new Random();

    bins = new Vector(38);
    for (int i=0; i<38; i++){
        bins.add(i, new Bin());
    }
}

void addOutcome(int bin, Outcome outcome){
    this.bins.elementAt(bin).add(outcome);
}

Bin next(){
    int rand = rng.nextInt(38);

    return bins.elementAt(rand);

}

Bin get(int bin){
    return  bins.elementAt(bin);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler does not know at runtime what you will get out of `bins.elementAt()`. Since you have not defined a type, it expects an object of any class (an `Object` instance), which may or may not be of class `Bin`.

So, what you have is (for the compiler) like

```
  Object a = new Bin();
  Bin b = a;
```

Since the compiler is not sure, it needs you to cast it to ensure that it will return the appropiated type (or fail if there is a cast error). Anyway, you must explicit that

```
  Object a = new Bin();
  Bin b = (Bin) a;    // compiles and works

  Object a = new String("Hello world");
  Bin b = (Bin) a;    // compiles but fails at runtime with ClassCastException.
```

The alternative is using generics to specify that the `Vector` will only contain `Bin` instances

```
  Vector<Bin> bins = new Vector<Bin>();
```

That way the compiler will be sure that `bins.getElement()` returns a `Bin` object.

Answer (score 1):

you should turn

```
Vector bins;
```

into

```
Vector<Bin> bins;
```

then it should work

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at Java-Generics(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

You have to change your Line

> `Vector bins;`

to

> `Vector<Bin> bins;`

which requires you to change your initialization from

> `bins = new Vector(38);`

to

> `bins = new Vector<Bin>(38);`

Hope I could help you.